# Text rendering bug in Safari?

Tags: text, safari, text-rendering

For some crazy reason, there are these boxes that are showing up on line breaks within text on a site that I am working on within Safari version 6.0.3 (8536.28.10) (see attached screen shot)

[image: random text boxes]

I've tested this out on a different Mac running the same version of Safari and I cannot replicate the issue. So, I am not sure what could be causing this issue. Both Mac's are running up to date versions of Mountain Lion. So far it only seems to appearing on one particular Mac.
The font on the site is using a Google font called Source Sans Pro.

Comment: It will be hard for people to answer with just a screenshot to go on. Have you tried other browsers on the problem machine? Have you cleared the cache?

Comment: @PeterG Yep, tried with other browsers and it's only happening on Safari on their machine. We also cleared the cache and rebooted the machine completely as well and the problem still existed. We eventually dropped using the font on that particular class. I'm still befuddled by it.